# Na destruição do componente quero executar um evento com reactjs

Tags: react

Eu tenho um componente e preciso disparar um evento toda vez que destruímos aquele componente. Eu estudei o ciclo de vida do componente pela documentação do react [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

La na documentação eu entendi sobre o `componentWillUnmount`, contudo, meu componente não é uma classe, e sim uma função. Nas minhas pesquisas eu vi que eu consigo a seguinte abordagem pra identificar ao sair do componente com useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
     return () => {
   // Será executado o que eu pedir     
};   
}, []);
```

O único problema disso é que ele é renderizado duas vezes, no momento em que destruímos o componente (O que é esperado) e quando montamos o componente (O que não é esperado).

Procurei algumas soluções pra esse problema e não consegui chegar em nada.

Comment: Não está muito claro, executar duas vezes! poderia exemplificar, porque não é para acontecer isso com esse código!

Comment: Consegui resolver amigo! Deixei a solução num comentário. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, é por conta do comportamento do StrictMode do react, li essa parte na documentação e em desenvolvimento quando vai ser montado um componente ele renderiza ele e desmonta para encontrar possíveis erros de performance etc e tal, e depois monta novamente logo em seguida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).